# Select unique product id and order by stock id desc

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, unique

I'm trying to get unique product from stock...

stock table:

```
id - product - quantity
1    2            0
2    3            5
3    2            19
4    4            3
5    2            8
```

result

```
id - product - quantity
5    2            8
4    4            3
2    3            5
```

it's working with

```
SELECT max(id) as id, 
product
FROM stock 
GROUP by product 
ORDER by id DESC
```

but I can't get last quantity of product
with this query I get:

```
id - product - quantity
1    2            0
2    3            5
4    4            3
```

I need latest quantity of the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your existing query in a subquery and join that on the table itself so you can get the other columns of the same row.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    stock a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  product, MAX(ID) id
            FROM    stock
            GROUP   BY product
        ) b ON  a.product = b.product
                AND a.ID = b.ID
ORDER   BY a.id DESC
```

Comment: You can get the same with a left join and no subquery. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your definition of "latest" is max(id), I think the easiest way is:

```
SELECT s.id, s.product, s.quantity
FROM stock s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stock s2 WHERE s2.product = s.product and s2.id > s.id);
```

Basically give me the stock rows where there is no row for the same product with a greater id.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a left join of the table with itself that filters only rows without one with higher id and same product, avoiding subquery and group by, which can be very expensive on large tables:

```
select p1.id, p1.product, p1.quantity from stock as p1 
left join test as p2 on p1.product = p2.product and p2.id> p1.id
where p2.id is null
order by p1.id desc;
```